# Why Hibernate re-update when querying objects causes Batch update returned unexpected row count?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-test

I am writing a Test class to test my DAO (ProjectDao). Only one table in the database (for Project) and no association in persistence object.

Here is my base test class (for @Before and @After methods):

```
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
public class DaoTestBase extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Autowired
protected ProjectDao projectDao;

@Autowired
protected List<Project> dummyProjects;

@Before
public void initTestData() throws Exception {
    projectDao.deleteAll();

    for (Project project : dummyProjects) {
        projectDao.saveOrUpdate(project);
    }
}

@After
public void clearTestData() throws Exception {
    projectDao.deleteAll();
}
}
```

And here is the actual Test class with 2 test methods:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath*:database/dummy-beans-test.xml",
    "classpath*:springcontext/*test.xml"})
public class ProjectDaoTest extends DaoTestBase {

private static final Comparator<Project> PROJECT_COMPARATOR = 
        new Comparator<Project>() {
    public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
        if (o1.getNumber() < o2.getNumber()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.getNumber() == o2.getNumber()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    };
};

@Test
public void shouldQueryTheSameAsDummyObjects() throws Exception {
    List<Project> projects = projectDao.getAll();
    Assert.assertEquals(dummyProjects.size(), projects.size());

    Set<Project> preProjects = new TreeSet<Project>(PROJECT_COMPARATOR);
    preProjects.addAll(dummyProjects);

    for (Project project : projects) {
        if (preProjects.contains(project)) {
            preProjects.remove(project);
        }
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(0, preProjects.size());
}

@Test
public void deleteSomeProjectsShouldRemoveThem() throws Exception {
    List<Project> projects = projectDao.getAll();
    Assert.assertEquals(3, projects.size());

    for (Project toDeleteProject : projects) {
        projectDao.delete(toDeleteProject);

        List<Project> remainProjects = projectDao.getAll();
        for (Project project : remainProjects) {
            if (project.getNumber() == toDeleteProject.getNumber()) {
                Assert.assertTrue(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when i ignore one of the test method above, everything is tested fine but when i test both of them, it will cause:

```
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Inspecting the Log i see that when executing first test, Hibernate do these SQL:

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    project_table
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    project_table
    (pro_customer, pro_end_date, pro_name, pro_number, pro_start_date, pro_status) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    project_table
    (pro_customer, pro_end_date, pro_name, pro_number, pro_start_date, pro_status) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    project_table
    (pro_customer, pro_end_date, pro_name, pro_number, pro_start_date, pro_status) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
select
    this_.id as id0_0_,
    this_.pro_customer as pro2_0_0_,
    this_.pro_end_date as pro3_0_0_,
    this_.pro_name as pro4_0_0_,
    this_.pro_number as pro5_0_0_,
    this_.pro_start_date as pro6_0_0_,
    this_.pro_status as pro7_0_0_ 
from
    project_table this_
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    project_table
```

And when executing second test, they do:

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    project_table
Hibernate: 
update
    project_table 
set
    pro_customer=?,
    pro_end_date=?,
    pro_name=?,
    pro_number=?,
    pro_start_date=?,
    pro_status=? 
where
    id=?
Hibernate: 
update
    project_table 
set
    pro_customer=?,
    pro_end_date=?,
    pro_name=?,
    pro_number=?,
    pro_start_date=?,
    pro_status=? 
where
    id=?
Hibernate: 
update
    project_table 
set
    pro_customer=?,
    pro_end_date=?,
    pro_name=?,
    pro_number=?,
    pro_start_date=?,
    pro_status=? 
where
    id=?
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    project_table
```

Before and after these Hibernate actions in each test, i noticed that Hibernate opened and closed Session (and rolled back transaction). So my questions are:

1/ Why in the @Before method of second test, Hibernate did not insert data (the data they inserted in the first method have been rolled back?!).

2/ Why in the second test method i only getAll (using criteria) and Hibernate updated the data?!

3/ Why is the `Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` is this case?

In the DAO's implementation i retrieved current Session from SessionFactory, do query using criteria. E.g. for getAll() method:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(type)
                .list()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your project entities are in fact Spring beans coming from the Spring context. The Spring context, by default, is shared between tests.

The first test attaches these entities to the session using `saveOrUpdate()` and thus generates an ID for them. Then it deletes them from the database.

The second test then calls `saveOrUpdate()` with these exact same Project instances as argument. Since they already have an ID, Hibernate considers that they're detached Project instances that should already exist in the database, and uses update queries to update them. But since they don't exist in the database anymore, the query fails.

You should not reuse Project entity instances between tests. Create the instances from scratch in your `@Before` method instead of getting them from the Spring context.

Comment: I changed the scope of these "dummy" projects to prototype and everything work fine. Thanks a lot (i still do not have enough reputation to vote your answer :-) ). By the way, i want to create some dummy data to test and if not a good practice to put them in spring context then where should i define them? I don't think define them in code is good!

Comment: Why wouldn't it good? They're Java objects needed by your test. It feels pretty natural to define them in Java, in your test.

Comment: But wait, how about my first question? The Session (and so the persistence context) is over after the first test, how the @Before method of the second test know that these instances have never changed since last time and by pass the inserts?

Comment: saveOrUpdate() doesn't know they haven't changed. That's why it's doing an update. It would do an insert if the entities didn't have an ID.